# Implicit differentiation of $e^{x^2+y^2} = xy$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I just want to reconfirm the steps needed to answer this question. Thank you

Find $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ in the followng:

$$e^{\large x^2 + y^2}= xy$$

I got this so far.

[image]

$\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}\frac{\dd x}{\dd y} e^{x^2}\cdot e^{y^2} = \frac{\dd x}{\dd y} xy$

$u=e^{x^2}$: $\frac{\dd u}{\dd x}=2x(e^{x^2})$
$v=e^{y^2}$: $\frac{\dd v}{\dd x}=2y(e^{y^2})\frac{\dd y}{\dd x}$

$u=x$: $\frac{\dd u}{\dd x}=1$
$v=y$: $\frac{\dd v}{\dd x}=\frac{\dd y}{\dd x}$

$$\begin{align}
e^{x^2}\cdot2y(e^{y^2})\frac{\dd y}{\dd x} + e^{y^2}\cdot 2x(e^{x^2}) &= x \frac{\dd y}{\dd x} + y\\
e^{x^2}\cdot2y(e^{y^2})\frac{\dd y}{\dd x} - x \frac{\dd y}{\dd x} &= y - e^{y^2}\cdot 2x(e^{x^2})\\
\frac{\dd y}{\dd x} \left[e^{x^2}\cdot2y(e^{y^2})-x\right] &= y - e^{y^2}\cdot 2x(e^{x^2})\\
\frac{\dd y}{\dd x} &= \frac{y - e^{y^2}\cdot 2x(e^{x^2})}{e^{x^2}\cdot2y(e^{y^2})-x}
\end{align}$$

Comment: What have you worked out so far? Please show us your steps.

Comment: Your notation is wrong. $\dfrac {\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy}$ is a variable, like $x$ and $y$ are. $\dfrac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}$ is an operator that acts on (implicitly defined) functions. Also, are you solving for $\dfrac {\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$, or $\dfrac {\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy}$?

Comment: Oh ok I didn't know that. I'm solving for dy/dx.

Comment: @AriffAziz [The picture you posted](http://i.stack.imgur.com/keZaC.jpg) is not very readable. Please, check whether what I wrote is along the line what you wanted to write there. If needed, edit it further.

Answer (score 2):

$ e^{(x^2+y^2)} $ can never equal $ x\,y $, because there is no real intersection of surfaces $ z=e^{(x^2+y^2)}  $ and $ z = x y  $.

The question of derivative $ \frac{dy}{dx} $  is  meaningless at least as far as real variables x and y are concerned.

EDIT1:

You really want implicit differential coefficient of $  e^{(x^2+y^2)} - x y  $ = c, when constant c is such that $ f(x,y) = e^{(x^2+y^2)} - x y -c = 0 $ is a real 2D contour along which the derivative is sought.

Answer (score 1):

$\bf edit:$ as you can see from the comments, there is no need to do any implicit differencing. the constraint $$e^{x^2+y^2} = xy$$  cannot be satisfied by any real $x, y.$ the formal differencing and the formal expression for $\frac{dy}{dx}$
is of no use.

---

the original post is kept here so that the comments make sense.

turn it into $$x^2 + y^2 = \ln |x| + \ln |y| $$ now difference this you get $$2x\, dx + 2y\, dy = \frac{dx}x + \frac{dy}{y} $$ which can be simplified as 
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{(1-2x^2)y}{(2y^2-1)x} \text{ and } e^{x^2 + y^2} = xy.$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was wondering if it is possible to do it without using logarithms?

Comment: Does this answer account for the possibility of $x, y \le 0$? Shouldn't you take the absolute value?

Comment: @GFauxPas, it doesn't really matter, because there are no real $(x,y)$ that satisfy the equation $e^{x^2+y^2}=xy$.

Comment: @BernardMassé, how do you see that?

Comment: $e^{x^2+y^2}>x^2+y^2>xy$

Comment: @Michael, thanks. ok i should have seen that.

Comment: It is not that there is no need to differentiate implicitly. One should know what is exactly required.

Answer (score 0):

$$ e^{x^2+y^2} =xy
\\ e^{x^2+y^2}\; [x^2+y^2]' =[x]'\, y+x\,[y]'
\\ e^{x^2+y^2}\; [2x+2y\,\color{blue}{y'}] =[1]\, y+x\,[\color{blue}{y'}]
\\ 2xe^{x^2+y^2}+2ye^{x^2+y^2}\,\color{blue}{y'} =y+x\,\color{blue}{y'}
\\ 2ye^{x^2+y^2}\,\color{blue}{y'}-x\,\color{blue}{y'} =y-2xe^{x^2+y^2}
\\ (2ye^{x^2+y^2}-x)\,\color{blue}{y'} =y-2xe^{x^2+y^2}
\\ \color{blue}{y' = \dfrac{y-2xe^{x^2+y^2}}{2ye^{x^2+y^2}-x}}  $$